# WHMCS, change language programmatically

Tags: internationalization, whmcs

Is there a way to change the WHMCS language programmaticaly, even with the use of hooks?

Comment: This actually needs more clarification where did you want the whmcs language to change client area, admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHMCS API doesn't have a function to change the language. Therefore, your best bet would be to use an action hook, and when that hook executes, you would need to change the language by directly interacting with the database. You would directly use a `mysql_query()` function, since the connection is already established by WHMCS itself.

Answer (score 6):

Client-side:
http://demo.whmcs.com/index.php?language=Spanish

Admin-side:
Setup->My account->Language

Answer (score 0):

As user1904473 said. In order to give the user an option for changing the language you have to add language to the query once:

```
<a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?language=English">English</a>
<a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?language=Portuguese-br">Portugues</a>
<a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?language=Spanish">Spanol</a>
<h2>{$LANG.accountstats}</h2>
```